# mysql query current time - interval not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a query that previously worked but the interval part no longer seems to work it just pulls up all my data

query is

```
SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE date = CURDATE() AND time > curtime()-INTERVAL 20 second
```

any idea's where i am going wrong?

EDIT, i should add im running mysql V 5.6.37 complied for linux

2nd Edit: I have added a photo of my table my desired result is to have all data rows from the previous 20 seconds of the Current time e.g. if the current time is 14:11:40 pull all data between 14:11:40 and 14:11:20  I have trucated data so i now only have today's date but date wasnt and issue just time even when i remove the data part it still doesn't work

Many thanks[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbfGX.png)

Comment: You're missing the plus or minus operator.

Comment: @Barmar sorry it is in there just missed it out here will update

Comment: What is the datatype of `time`?

Comment: TIME  stored as hh:mm:ss

Comment: If it's stored as `hh:mm:ss` then it's a string, not a `TIME`. `TIME` is stored as a number, it's converted to `hh:mm:ss` when displayed.

Comment: so i gets pulled in to mysql using node-red with the js of var time = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0,8);  the column value is set to TIME and the data of the column is HH:MM:SS and all has been working fine but after going on it today i cant get it to retrieve the desired query results using interval

Comment: Your query works for me: http://rextester.com/LAP72410

Comment: see now im not sure why it doesnt work for me what i want is for instance:

Comment: Please edit the question with sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You say it's returning all rows. Even when the date doesn't match today's date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM bluserve_wp635.OSM 
WHERE ADDTIME(CONVERT(date, DATETIME), time) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 SECOND)
```

Comment: I think I just wrote a nonsense, you cannot compare two time, but only two datetime. What the meaning of the comparison between 05 september 7:00AM et 04 september 9:00AM? I think you have to build a real datetime before the comparison

Comment: Why don't you think you can compare times? They don't have a date in them. He's split his datetime into two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Now Solved stupidly i didnt take into account the server the mysql database is hosted on and it had resolved itself back to local time CAl, US rather than GB thank you all for your help